# Questions about the *business* of photography: on or off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious to hear whether folks think questions about the business side of professional photography would be on- or off-topic.  A few hypothetical examples:

- a magazine wants to buy a photo, how much should they pay?
- what are the pros and cons of Software X for estimating/invoicing photography clients?
- what are the implications of doing photography on a "work for hire" contract?

I see it as a gray area, as we already have some questions such as those concerning legal matters, model releases, etc.  Personally I wouldn't mind seeing business questions but then again I'm also in the business of photography :)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would say it is definitively *on* topic, as a professional photographer (or even a pro-am) would be interested in such topics.

Answer (score 13):

As someone who is not in the business of photography and has no intentions to ever enter it, I nonetheless find the business questions fascinating.

So yes, I vote they are on topic.

Answer (score 9):

There have already been [some questions regarding certain legal issues](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal), so your last suggestion is definitely "on topic". I can see information on forming a price as being of interest and on topic. Questions on invoicing software and estimate preparations *might* get a better response over at [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/), but it may be worth seeing how they're received here, if they are particularly relevant to photography.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely on topic. As a pro myself, I find that the whole of my life is geared around photography and photography is geared around my life. Getting paid is one aspect of, guess what, photography! But to go a touch deeper than that surface level rant, I've seen many questions regarding copyright and protection of work from amateurs on the main site. This is a business sided question, though perhaps they're not after money but protection.

Anyway, my vote is for yes, business is a part of photography. Just as lighting is. And focal length is. And packing the right weather gear is. Ad infinitum.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely on topic - especially as the first question many people ask me is "Are you professional?"

(I'm not, but I do have one of those big ol' "professional" camera-thingamies!).

I think that photography is quite unique in the way that the notion of a professional pervades the whole thing.  I mean, if someone said they were very into football, or a keen angler, you wouldn't immediately think of asking if they made their living doing it, but somehow photography is different.

Not sure if I'm making my point very well, so take it or leave it  ;)

PS.  Splendid question, by the way.